# decrypting protected pdf with user password by itext

Tags: java, itext

While decrypting protected pdf  with user password by **itext**. showing in console as Usage:

```
PdfContentReaderTool <pdf file> [<output file>|stdout] [<page num>]
```

Help am new to the **itext**

Comment: What code are you using for Decryption?

Comment: PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("D:/Sample1.pdf", "password".getBytes());
     PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("/NoPasswordPDF.pdf"));
     stamper.close();
     reader.close();

Comment: There is no "PdfContentReaderTool" class or string in the current iText 5.5.x, so that output is not an output of some iText class. Probably it is some tool you created and which is initialized as a side effect or you use manipulated iText jars.

Comment: As your follow-up question ["PdfContentReaderTool <pdf file> <output file>|stdout <page num> extracting Protected pdfs by using Zip4j"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41606781/1729265) makes clear, your problem is not caused by iText at all. Probably you simply start the `main` method` of the wrong class.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this code, it's working fine in my case:

```
public class PDFUtils {

    public static final String SOURCE_FILE = "encrypted.pdf";
    public static final String DESTINATION_FILE = "decrypted.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        File file = new File(DESTINATION_FILE );
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new PDFUtils ().decryptPdf(SOURCE_FILE , DESTINATION_FILE );
    }

    public void decryptPdf(String srcFile, String destFile) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(srcFile, "XXX".getBytes());
        System.out.println(new String(reader.computeUserPassword()));
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(destfile));
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Usage:  PdfContentReaderTool <pdf file> [<output file>|stdout] [<page num>] still getting the same error.